# Im having trouble installing mongodb.latest version?Please can someone help instal mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
Err:8 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done      
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The repository for MongoDB is found at `https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu`. Where did you get the information for `http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart` from 

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I think I need to remove it and reinstall it again.